# Generating dynamic music audio output with midi

Tags: android, midi

I have developed a music score application for android tablets which is targeting a minimum sdk level of 14.

I am seeking a means whereby I can "play" the score.

I have started to look at MIDI, but have seen that it is really only supported from SDK level 23 and later.

Is there a good, reliable midi synth output solution available for android, which will not cost the earth to use?

Answer (score 0):

Android includes the SonivoxEAS synth. This is the cheapest one, in many ways. There are also open source synths like FluidSynth, which is LGPL licensed. Both can play MIDI files. SonivoxEAS uses an internal wave table soundfont, so no additional files are required. FluidSynth needs an external SF2 soundfont, which takes more storage space.

Here are some examples using SonivoxEAS:

This [C++ project](https://github.com/pedrolcl/Linux-SonivoxEas) for Linux uses the SonivoxEAS, and shows how to play MIDI files using this library.

This [Java project](https://github.com/pedrolcl/android/tree/master/NativeGMSynth) for Android requires the SDK 23 because it uses the Android MIDI API that was introduced with Android 6, but SonivoxEAS can be used (via JNI) with older Android versions. My [VMPK for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.vmpk.free) uses it and is compatible with  Android 4.0 or later.

About documentation: the official source for MIDI specifications is [midi.org](https://www.midi.org/specifications) including Standard MIDI Files. The [SonivoxEAS documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sonivox/+/refs/heads/master/docs/) is available from the AOSP Git repository. And finally, for any further questions, use **StackOverflow** :-)

Comment: Thanks for that, however SonivoxEAS I understand is only available with SDK 23, where as I am looking for SDK 14.  In addition, I am wanting to link via an interface as opposed to creating a file and then sending it to the synth.

Comment: It has been in Android [for ages](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sonivox/+refs) but you need to understand that it is not part of the SDK, it is a native library.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.  I have been trying to find tutorials or examples of how to use this - never done any midi stuff before - without much success. Can you point me where to look for this, or perhaps you might be willing to help ?